# Mark the opening ``` with language

Tags: python

I have such a following note

````
In [362]: !cat data.md                                                                                            
**File Permission Related Commands**

These commands are used to change permissions of the files

```
72. chmod octal file-name                : Changes the permissions of file to octal
    chmod 777 /data/test.c                   : Sets rwx permission for owner , group and others
```

**Network Related Commands**

These commands are used to view and edit network configurations related aspects of the system

```
75. ifconfig -a        : Displays all network interface and set ip address
````

I'd like to mark the ``` ``` with ```python```,
so I should change the opening ``` to ```python

````
In [363]: f = open("data.md", "r+")                                                                               

In [364]: data = f.read()                                                                                         

In [365]: import re                                                                                               

In [366]: re.sub(r"^(```)", "```bash", data)                                                                      
Out[366]: '**File Permission Related Commands**\n\nThese commands are used to change permissions of the files\n\n```\n72. chmod octal file-name      \t\t     : Changes the permissions of file to octal\n    chmod 777 /data/test.c
````

However, nothing changed.

How could I get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` matches the beginning of the string in normal mode. To make it match the beginning of the line pass `re.MULTILINE` to `re.sub`

````
re.sub(r"^(```)", "```bash", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
````

Edit: To correctly only subsitute the opening pair do

````
re.sub(r'```([^`]+)```', r'```bash\1```', data) 
# don't actually need ^ and MULTILINE in your example
````

Comment: thank you. Is it possible just replace the opening \```? leave closing pair unchanged?

Comment: why `r` is required in r'```bash\1```', if absent, not work, but caret is not a meta charactor.

Comment: Because `'\1'` is the same as `'\x01'`, AKA [start of heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH). `r'\1'` however is the same as `'\\1'` with an escaped backslash.